# Why Am I getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException in my Android Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner, indexoutofboundsexception

Hello I'm new to android studio and I'm making a registration section, the project is running fine on the phone without any error but the problem is that I'm using a spinner in which I've inserted some values, now some of the values can be selected like **Rising Star and Ethnically Black and White is working fine** and we can move further but as soon as  some other option like **Rnagoli** is selected the logcat shows an error :

```
01-28 22:23:43.824 23165-23165/myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti, PID: 23165
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:344)
at android.widget.AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(AdapterView.java:783)
at myapp.hp.com.abhivyakti.Cells.FineArts.FARegisterFragment.onItemSelected(FARegisterFragment.java:115)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:924)
at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:913)
at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:883)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

however in other section I used the same code but the Spinner is working fine. I cannot be able to figure out the solution of my problem.
Please help me with this. I'm just giving out my code for the same.

```
public class FARegisterFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


public FARegisterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private Button button;
private String string,string1;
private Spinner sp1,sp2;
private EditText editText1,editText2,editText3,editText4,editText5;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_faregister, container, false);
    button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsButton);
    sp1 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsSpinner1);
    sp2 = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsSpinner2);
    editText1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsEditText1);
    editText2 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsEditText2);
    editText3 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsEditText3);
    editText4 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsEditText4);
    editText5 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.FineArtsEditText5);
    //enables the spinner to be clickable
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)this);
    //inputs tge sting into the array
    String[] str = {"Select Event","Rising Star","Ethnically Black and White",
            "Rangoli","Paint and Spray","Theme Painting"};
    //array is been populated into the arrayadapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,str);
    //dropdown menu vie layout finalised
    aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //spinner is been assinged the string
    sp1.setAdapter(aa);

    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)this);
    String[] str1 = {"Select Member","1","2"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,str1);
    aa1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp2.setAdapter(aa1);

    //button event
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (string.toString().equals("Select Event")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Event not selected please fill", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if ((editText1.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Contact left please fill", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if ((editText2.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "College Name left please fill", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (string1.toString().equals("Select Member")) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Member not selected please fill", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if ((editText3.getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Participant's Name left please fill", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if ((editText4.getText().toString().equals("")) || (editText5
                    .getText().toString().equals(""))) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        " Detail Entry left please fill", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent emailintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[]{"c3club2016@gmail.com"});
                emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "FINEARTS Registration"
                        + " " + "via Android App");
                emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        "NAME OF EVENT:" + " " + string + "\n\nPARTICIPANT'S NAME:"
                                + " " + editText3.getText().toString()
                                + "\n\nNUMBER OF PARTICIPANT:" + " " + string1
                                + "\n\nPARTICIPANT'S BRANCH:" + " " + editText4.getText().toString()
                                + "\n\nPARTICIPANT'S YEAR:"
                                + " " + editText5.getText().toString()
                                + "\n\nCOLLEGE NAME:"
                                + " " + editText2.getText().toString() + " "
                                + "\n\nCONTACT:" + " " + editText1.getText().toString());
                emailintent.setType("message/rfc882");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailintent,
                        "Choose email client"));
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> pWRent, View view, int position, long id) {
    string = sp1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    string1 = sp2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> pWRent) {

}}
```

Your help will boost up my working process and will give me a lesson to learn for my future. Thank You in advance.

Comment: `however in other section I used the same code but the Spinner is working fine` not possible because both Adapter data-source Array is different size **6 and 3** and when 4th item is selected in Spinner1 and same `position ` is used for retrieving selected value from Spinner2 in `onItemSelected ` which causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException `

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access position 3 here

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> pWRent, View view, int position, long id) {
    string = sp1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    string1 = sp2.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}
```

This does not work because `sp2` contains only 3 elements (with indices 0 .. 2).

Comment: What should I do then for sorting out the problem. Please suggest the code which can remove the error and how should I be able to select the element at third position i.e., Rangoli.

Comment: You will learn nothing if somebody gives you the code to copy and paste. I have pointed out where the problem is, now try to find a solution.

Comment: Well I'm thinking to define the string1 in another section but where there is no option left for me other than making the sp2 as equal as sp1. But this is not the good idea. Please give me one more hint. Don't give me the code but at least give me something as you gave me before which will help me to move further. I'm new to this, and this problem is quiet tricky.

Comment: Both spinners will call the same method `onItemSelected` but you want to handle them differently. One way is to check which spinner triggered the call and then handle it accordingly. Hint: the spinner is passed as parameter `pWRent`.

Comment: I did it. Thanks I just created the anonymous class of  OnItemSelectedListener individually for each spinner and its working fine.